# Opencart 2.1.0.2 Getting error from installing ocmod.zip

Tags: php, installation, opencart, opencart2.x, ocmod

I've just started to use 2.1.0.2 and I'm trying to convert over some of my own extensions I built for my 1.5.6.4 store.

I have started with a fresh install of 2.1.0.2 and I built a very basic extension, I'm wanting to move over to the extension installer to install my future additions to my store instead of using vqmod.

I have made my testerextension.ocmod.zip, inside this is:

```
install.xml 
/upload/
/admin/
/catalog/
```

However when I use the installer to upload testerextension.ocmod.zip I'm getting the following error:

Directory containing files to be uploaded could not be found

I have tracked this down to the ftp() class as I can see this error can be trigged in another class.

I've also looked into the storage temp folder to find a folder unzipped called: testerextension.ocmod NOT upload.

To rule out if there was an issue with OC system I have uploaded another extension from the extension store with the similar directory structure and similar ocmod.zip name only for it to correctly install.

Therefore i'm unsure as to why this would be happening, I understand the system is looking for the upload folder in the temp folder but it's not there as it's one level deeper in the testerextension.ocmod - but as you can see from the directory structure above this shouldn't be happening.

Does anyone have any idea where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

i have a solution

1.Download LocalCopy.zip

- http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=18892
  2.unzip in install from extenstion installer in admin panel

Note:in case you get error of ftp than set ftp from store->setting->ftp and   uninstall LocalCopy extenstion and install again extenstion installer

if you still get problem contact me

Comment: This isenselab extension fix is a life saver

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

This happened cause I compressed the directory of the extension. The rigth way is compress the files of the extension.

Comment: I do this and have a new error **Invalid file type!**

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like this..

1. make "upload" directory , inside this directory put files which you want to add more functionality over default opencart gave..
   Note:- do not use same files as admin or catalog ,to override..
2. make "install.xml" where you can use search and replace functions to work your extension properly..
3. Use "install.sql" where you can put only database related queries only..
4. use "install.php" where you can type code as normal PHP coding standard..

   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5. Now last select this whole Files You created , and directly compress this files and name this zip and than upload this zip,having ".ocmod.zip" extension..
6. - Before You upload your extension install below 
     http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=18892 extension...
7. Check below Link and download it's zip ,and make your zip structure as it is..
   http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=20706&filter_search=Manufacturedescription.ocmod&filter_license=0&page=2

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the extension installer. Instead, unzip the downloaded package and upload the contents of the "upload" folder to your store's root directory via FTP. This will merge the files into your store.