# Directory containing files to be uploaded could not be found in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am getting this error while installing extension. I am using OpenCart **2.1.0.2**. Please help me out from this error

> Directory containing files to be uploaded could not be found!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opencart 2.1.0.2 Getting error from installing ocmod.zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258574/opencart-2-1-0-2-getting-error-from-installing-ocmod-zip)

Comment: please add more information on your question becasue there is a lot more reasons to occur this situation error